# Create a Loop in R on participants; per participant 1 boxplot .tiff is created

Tags: r, loops, boxplot

Dear Stack overflow community,

**I would like to perform a loop of 4 participants with different .csv files (1 per participant).
For each subject I would like to produce a bar plot relying "sex(male, female)" on the x axis with the "Proportion of correct answer" on the y axis).**

Here is showed how each .csv file appear when opened:
I want to add names to the factors c("observernumber","trial","numstim","memo","sex","corResp","curresp","success")

```
1   1   284 high    female  a   a   1
2   2   190 low     male    l   l   1
3   3   224 low     male    l   l   1
4   4   218 high    male    l   l   1
5   5   137 high    male    l   l   1
6   6   45  high    female  a   a   1
7   7   87  high    female  a   a   1
8   8   249 high    female  a   a   1
9   9   27  low     male    l   l   1
10  10  53  low     male    l   l   1
11  11  92  low     female  a   a   1
12  12  283 low     male    l   l   1
```

I start by giving the .csv names per participant:

```
obsNames = c("1_gender","2_gender","3_gender","4_gender")
nsubj <- length(obsNames)
```

I preallocate a matrix reading the obsNames:

```
allData = c() 
for (i in 1:obsNames) { 
  dat = read.csv(sprintf("%s_gender.csv", obsNames[i]), header = FALSE, sep = ";") 
  obsIndex = rep(i,nrow(dat)) 
  allData = rbind(allData, cbind(obsIndex,dat)) 
}
```

I name the total factors I have:

```
names(allData) = c("subj", "trial", "sex", "success")
```

**I want to plot for each of the 4 current subjects a .tiff file that has to show a)b)c):**

a) Name of the current observer as title

```
paste(obsNames[curSubj], ".tiff", sep = "")
```

b) "sex(male, female)" factor on the x axis

```
"sex"
```

c)with the "Proportion of correct answer" factor on the y axis

```
"success"
```

**I would like to produce a boxplot for each of the participants, how should I finish this script?
How do I name x and y values?:**

```
for(curSubj in 1:nsubj){
  tiff(file = paste(obsNames[curSubj], ".tiff", sep = "")) 
  barCenters = barplot(
    main = paste(obsNames[curSubj],".tiff",sep = ""),
    yaxt = "n",
    ylab = "Proportion Correct",
    xlab = "Gender"
  ) 
  mgp.axis(labels = c("Female","Male")) 
  dev.off() 
}
```

**Is there an error using???**

```
curSubj
```

Comment: are you getting an error message? Why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: You can simplify and do `for(curSubj in obsNames)` and remove `obsNames` from the loop, but I don't think that's the amin problem.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(allData)` in the question, or if it's too big the output of `dput(head(allData, 20))`, please?

Comment: Can you please clean up the code formatting (such as adding indents) so that your code is more readable. Also remove anything not relevant for the problem at hand (such as color, which from what you said is not something you are having problems with).

Comment: Hope code and questions are clearer with the new edits

Comment: @RuiBarradas I added in the beginning all the data. Is that helpful?

Comment: In the text you say *boxplot*  but in the code you have *barplot*. Which one do you want'

Comment: @RuiBarradas Bar plot

Comment: @RuiBarradas In case that the initial .csv for each subject has more columns and no names of the factors. How should I proceed in order to add names for the factors? c("observernumber","trial","numstim","memo","sex","corResp","curresp","success") I entered the changes in the script.

Answer (score 0):

The following creates one TIFF file with a bar plot per CSV file whose names match the pattern `"gender.csv"`.
It uses `ggplot2` graphics.

First, read in the files.

```
csv_files <- list.files(pattern = "gender\\.csv")
df_list <- lapply(csv_files, read.csv)
obsNames <- sub("\\.csv", "", csv_files)
df_list <- lapply(seq_along(df_list), function(i){
  Y <- cbind.data.frame(obsIndex = obsNames[i], df_list[[i]])
})
```

Now the bar plots, saved in TIFF files.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

for(i in seq_along(df_list)){
  g <- ggplot(df_list[[i]], aes(x = sex)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), 
             stat = "count", position = "dodge") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
    ylab(label = "Proportion of correct answer") +
    ggtitle(obsNames[i])

  outfile <- paste0(obsNames[i], ".tiff")
  tiff(filename = outfile)
  print(g)
  dev.off()
}
```

## Data creation code.

The following code creates 4 csv files in thee working directory, with the structure of the table posted in the question.

```
f <- function(i, n){
  sex <- sample(c("male", "female"), n, TRUE)
  success <- rbinom(n, 1, prob = 0.5)
  df <- data.frame(trial = seq_len(n), sex, success)
  write.csv(df, paste0(i, "_gender.csv"), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}

set.seed(1234)
n <- sample(20:50, 4)
lapply(1:4, function(i) f(i, n = n[i]))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help Rui! =) !

Comment: I added a further  question in the beginning of my answer, changing the columns contained in the 4 csv. Thank you a lot!